# React: Event is null when trying to pass state ot parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

When using React libraries the `onChange` method can be used to pass state to the parent component like this:

```
export class Parent extends React.Component<{}, { foo: string }> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Input
                value={this.state.foo}
                onChange={this.handleFooChange}
            />
        );
    }

    handleFooChange = (event: any) => {
        this.setState({
            foo: event.target.value
        });
    }
}
```

It changes the state in the parent as expected. I want to utilize the `onChange` property for my own component, which wraps yet another library component, but can't seem to get it to work. I essentially just want to pass the `Dropdown` value to the Parent through the `Picker`.

```
interface Props{
    onChange: any;
}

interface State{
    picked: string;
}

export class PickerComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange = (event: any) => {
        this.setState({
            picked: event.target.value,    //is null
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Input
                value={this.state.picked}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of null` for the event in `handleChange` in the above simplified implementation.

Here is something similar on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/LzWZvb), but here even the parent contains a call to `bind()` which is somewhat confusing. Any help or alternative solution is welcome.
`Dropdown` and `Input` are taken from Fluent UI if that matters.

EDIT: typo

Comment: Your `onChange` in the second code block is set to `this.handleDateChange`, but there is no `handleDateChange` method in that class. If we assume that's just a simple typo in the question, the code shown should work. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Side note: In the second code block, you've should `handleChange` defined as a property initialized with an arrow function, and you've also shown `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`. You don't need the latter with the former, it's a no-op for arrow functions (it wouldn't be if there were more arguments to `bind`, but with just one, it is). With that code in your constructor, you could define `handleChange` as a standard method, which would be more useful for mocking during testing and subclasses (though subclasses are rare with React components).

Comment: Does modifying `<Input>` to `<input>` works?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for this explanation, it was really helpful in figuring out the solution.

Comment: @ShriHari, It is `Input` as proposed. The component works as expected when called for itself.

Answer (score 1):

The error was actually rooted in the behaviour of the wrapped `Input` component from Fluent UI which returns an `event` and `data` through `onChange`. Instead of expecting `event.target.value` the received value lies in `data.value`. If the state is needed in the child component and the parent, `handleChange` should look like this in the child. It can be left out entirely if the state is not needed here.

```
interface PickerProps {
      onChange: any;
  }
  
  interface PickerState {
      picked: string;
  }
  
  export class Picker extends React.Component<PickerProps, PickerState> {
  
      constructor(props: any) {...}

      handleChange = (e: any, data: any) => {
          this.setState({
              picked: data.value,
          });
          this.props.onChange(e, data);
      };
  
      render() {
          return (
              <Input
                  onChange={this.handleChange} //call this.props.onChange if state is only needed in parent
              />
          );
      }
  }
```

Parent can call on the child by using the exact same `handleChange` method and passing it to the Child as

```
<Picker
     onChange={this.handleChangeButInParent}
/>
```

One might also just pass data.value to the parent.